# How to collapse/expand Razor components using Blazor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I'm currently implementing a form to create a new user along with their respective user rights. In this form, I have about 30 different IT systems and if the user account should have the access rights for that specific IT system, I want to provide a panel to the admin where some extra information must be entered regarding that specific IT system. I want to implement this using razor components. What I have so far is the core view for my "new user form" as well as a razor component for the additional information of a specific IT system. By clicking the + button, I want the component to be visible / expand right below the IT system. That's what It looks like so far:

[image]

The **new user form:**

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 font-weight-bold">GOODWILL PKW/Smart</div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>Add</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>Change</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>Remove</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">                    
                    <button @onclick="@collapseGoodwill">+</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <ModalGoodwillPKW ></ModalGoodwillPKW>

@code {

public void collapseGoodwill() {     


        }

}
```

The **component**:

```
<div class="panel panel-default border">
    <div class="panel-heading alert-primary">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Goodwill PKW/smart</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 font-weight-bold">Profile</div>

                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="CB_c" />
                    <label>Salesman</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="CB_r" />
                    <label>Administrator</label>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Normally, I would use JQuery in the "collapseGoodwill" method to add a .collapse class to this element. But since I am experimenting with Blazor, I'd like to know if there is a 100% Javascript /JQuery free way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Within Blazor, you always follow the pattern:

```
change data 
    --> new view rendered
```

Anytime you want to change the component's UI from outside, you should do it by changing the data (model/state/parameter/context/...).

As for this scenario, you can add a `Collapsed` field to indicate whether the panel itself is collapsed now:

```
<div class="panel panel-default border @Collapse">
    <div class="panel-heading alert-primary">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Goodwill PKW/smart</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 font-weight-bold">Profile</div>

                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="CB_c" />
                    <label>Salesman</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="CB_r" />
                    <label>Administrator</label>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Collapse{get;set;}="collapse"; // hide by default
}
```

And whenever you want to collapse it, just set this parameter to `collapse`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 font-weight-bold">GOODWILL PKW/Smart</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>Add</label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>Change</label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>Remove</label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">                    
        <button @onclick="e => this.Collapsed = !this.Collapsed">
            @( this.Collapsed ? "+" : "-")
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<ModalGoodwillPKW Collapse="@( this.Collapsed ? "collapse": "")" ></ModalGoodwillPKW>

@code {
    private bool Collapsed = true;
}
```

#### Demo:

[image]

---

**[Edit]** : we can even refactor the above code to expose less information by changing the field from string to boolean.

The `ModalGoodwillPKW.razor`:

```
<div class="panel panel-default border @(Collapsed? "collapse": "" ) ">
    <div class="panel-heading alert-primary">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Goodwill PKW/smart</h3>
    </div>

   ...


@code{
    [Parameter]
    public bool Collapsed{get;set;}= true; // hide by default
}
```

The `UserForm.razor`:

```
<div class="row">
    ...
    <div class="col-sm-4">                 
        <button @onclick="e => this.Collapsed = !this.Collapsed">
            @( this.Collapsed ? "+" : "-")
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<ModalGoodwillPKW Collapsed="@Collapsed" ></ModalGoodwillPKW>

@code {
    private bool Collapsed = true;
}
```

Comment: I've done this without blazor code behind with collapse with bootstrap:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/ but good to see the state change can be done via blazor/razor. Can you easily animate the collapse? If you're adding new elements inside the collapsed div, can you add them before the collapse is opened?

Comment: @ GisMofx , I tried your link in my Blazor component but did not work unfortunately, could you please advice?

Comment: @GisMofx - I tried to use Bootstrap, but it didn't work for me...did you have to wire in any middleware in the startup.cs?

Comment: @JohnnyWu Nope. Should just work with vanilla bootstrap. I was going to make an example, but here's a good post on it: https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/ Using collapse.

Comment: @GisMofx...thx  that was a great resource.  However, it talks about collpasing the component w/ Razor not Bootstrap.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, I had a dynamic list of sections that I wanted to collapse, and I couldn't get the bootstrap `data-toggle` approach to work due to Blazor mis-handling of # anchor tags.

I used the component idea:

```
<div class="row">
@if (Collapsed)
{
    <span @onclick="@Toggle" class="oi oi-plus mr-1"/>
}
else
{ 
    <span @onclick="@Toggle" class="oi oi-minus mr-1"/>
}
@Title
</div>

@if(!Collapsed)
{
    @ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool Collapsed { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    void Toggle()
    {
        Collapsed = !Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Which I could then use like this:

```
            @foreach (var i in c.Request)
        {
            <Collapsable Title="@i.SectionName" Collapsed="true">
                <ChildContent>
                    @foreach (var kvp in i.Values)
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-6 font-weight-bolder">@kvp.Key</div>
                            <div class="col-5">@kvp.Value</div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </ChildContent>
            </Collapsable>
        }
```

This seems to work well, each section is independently collapsible.
I've not tried it nested though.

Comment: Fantastic solution!  Thank you.  Now we just need to expand that so we can have a "Open All" "Collapse All" button that affects all of the regions.  Should just be another parameter one can pass in.... :)  Again, super helpful - thanks!

Comment: @LanceLarsen-MicrosoftMVP I think you would just need some kind of event handler on the Collapsed property, then that could be controlled by just a variable outside.   Though you might not even need that, not sure how the property interaction fully works yet, only just made my first app:)

Comment: I'm newer to Blazor, is the first code block the component file? Perhaps you would name it "Collapse.razor" and save it in a Shared folder? And is the 2nd block the template markup you would add to a razor page?

Comment: @KrisBunda The 1st code block is the entire `<Collapsable />` definition so yes you would add that to a `Collapsable.razor` file, and then the 2nd code block is an example usage of the component. Note if you change the name of the file, then the tag name also changes to match that file name.

Comment: @cjb110 I used your example and it does work very well in Blazor without having to add popper and jquery and bootstrap js scripts to every page via your layout file. I posted below to show how I adapted your component design to add a bootstrap button as the toggle, as trying to do that in Blazor is what brought me here, and this is viable alternative and may be even better as it's a reusable component.

Answer (score 3):

### Blazor "#Collapse" div with Bootstrap Toggle Button

I took @cjb110 's excellent sample code above and changed it to use a bootstrap badge button as the toggle, which is how I often add more verbose help info to a form field group, by hiding it behind a toggle and using a bootstrap or material info button for if a user wants it.

[image: toggle closed and toggle open]

#### Component Part

Here's the component part, which you'd probably add to your Blazor solution's Client project's `Shared` folder as file name `Collapsible.razor` (note: Blazor component file names are to be capitalized--I think)

```cs
<div class="my-1">
  <h3>@Title</h3>

    @if (Collapsed)
    {
      <button @onclick="@Toggle" class="badge badge-info mr-2" role="button" >
        @ButtonText
      </button> 
    }
    else
    { 
      <button @onclick="@Toggle" class="badge badge-info mr-2" role="button" >
        @ButtonText
      </button> 
    }
  <label>
    @LabelText
  </label>  
</div>

@if(!Collapsed)
{
  <div class="card alert alert-info mb-3" role="alert">
    @ChildContent
  </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool Collapsed { get; set; }

    //input params coming from from page
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string ButtonText { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string LabelText { get; set; }

    void Toggle()
    {
        Collapsed = !Collapsed;
    }
}
```

#### Template Part

I call this the "template" part. You can change the
`Title` text,
`ButtonText`,
I use these info-btn toggles typically in forms, so I added a
`<label/>` tag with `LabelText`.

In the `<ChildContent/>` area, in the component file I set it up as a Bootstrap `alert` class `div`, so it doesn't require a `<p>` tag, but put anything in here you want to show up when the toggle is opened.

```html
<Collapsible 
    Title="" 
    ButtonText="Info" 
    LabelText="Search People & Assign Roles: " 
    Collapsed="true">

    <ChildContent>
        Find a person, add their role to the product (i.e.: Estimator, Foreman, Customer)
    </ChildContent>
</Collapsible>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some long and good answers.  I thought I'd come in with the most important punchline, though.

You can hide whatever you want based on C# conditional logic.  So you will VERY often use something like:

```
<div @onclick="()=>IsOpened = !IsOpened">Click on me to show the hidden control.</div>

@if (IsOpened){
    <MyHiddenControl />
}

@code {
     bool IsOpened;
}
```

Comment: Voted down because. . . ?

Comment: maybe because it doesn't address the question?  An `if` approach doesn't really scale to multiple dynamic collapsible sections.

Comment: (1)  Yes, it does, and quite easily.  (2)  Neither does the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing issues with the accordion collapse in my project.

This is how I fixed the bootstrap collapse issue in my Blazor app.

I simply copied these dependencies in the `index.html` file in Blazor webapp and it worked fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h

Let us know if this works for anyone else