# Recursive markup in Blazor

Tags: recursion, nested, blazor

I have a LogModel that has a Children property of type LogModel, so a recursive/nested structure.
There is also a Collapsed bool property and a Description string.

I am trying to display this in Blazor server side markup, but cant figure out how to process the recursive piece.

I want it to show the Description, with a +/- button which has @onclick that toggles the Collapse property, which then controls the collapse class in bootstrap, collapsing/hiding all children from display.
Like this example:  [How to collapse/expand Razor components using Blazor syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538154/how-to-collapse-expand-razor-components-using-blazor-syntax)

My 2nd idea was to do the recursive piece inside Code, which returns a MarkupString.
This displayed ok, but then I couldnt work out how to bind the +/- button to an event to toggle the collapsed property, because the @onlick cant be done from inside MarkupString from what I've read.

Thanks in advance,
Aaron.

Comment: Some example code would help showing where you've got to so far?

Comment: How many level do you have or do you want to expose?

Comment: its not infinite, but I would like the code to handle it infinitely with a truly recursive/nested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution based on the information you've given.  It's not pretty: you'll need to sort the Bootstrap CSS out to suite your needs.

##### LogModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow.Answers
{
    public class LogModel
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<LogModel> Children { get; set; } = new List<LogModel>();

    }
}
```

##### LogDisplayControl.razor

```
@namespace StackOverflow.Answers
<div class="container m-0 p-1 border border-secondary">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-11">
            @this.Model.Description
        </div>
        @if (this.hasChildren)
        {
            <div class="col-1">
                <button class="btn @this.buttonCss" type="button" @onclick="ToggleShow">
                    @buttonText
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    @if (this.Show)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                @if (this.hasChildren)
                {
                    @foreach (var child in this.Model.Children)
                    {
                        <LogDisplayControl Model="child"></LogDisplayControl>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public LogModel Model { get; set; }

    private bool Show;

    private void ToggleShow()
        => this.Show = !this.Show;

    private bool hasChildren => this.Model?.Children?.Count > 0;

    private string buttonText => this.Show ? "Hide" : "Show";

    private string buttonCss => this.Show ? "btn-dark" : "btn-primary";

    private string HeaderCols => this.hasChildren ? "col-11" : "col-12";

}
```

##### Demo Page

```
@page "/Accordion"
@foreach (var child in Model)
{
    <LogDisplayControl Model="child" />
}

@code {

    private List<LogModel> Model = new List<LogModel>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var model1_1_1 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 1.1.1" };
        var model1_1_2 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 1.1.2" };
        var model1_1 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 1.1", Children = new List<LogModel> { model1_1_1, model1_1_2 } };

        var model1_2 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 1.2" };

        var model1 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 1", Children = new List<LogModel> { model1_1, model1_2 } };

        var model2_1_1 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 2.1.1" };

        var model2_1 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 2.1", Children = new List<LogModel> { model2_1_1 } };

        var model2 = new LogModel { Description = "Log Model 2", Children = new List<LogModel> { model2_1 } };

        Model.Add(model1);
        Model.Add(model2);
    }
}
```

Comment: A recursive initializer would have been cool. Far less code. Want me to edit one in?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, feel free.  This was my first shot before the caffeine kicked in this morning.  I can already see where to can be improved!

Comment: You are amazing, thankyou so very much. I was wondering if you could use a control that referenced itself.  I will try this out now.  I'll mark it as answered soon.